# How can I save a command coroutine in a variable that can be accessed through another command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, coroutine

What I'm trying to implement in my discord bot is a system that stops a running command coroutine as soon as another command is invoked by the same user, in an attempt to sort of keep a unique active session for each user.

So essentially I need to be able to access that coroutine object and stop it from within another coroutine.

What I've tried so far looks logic to me but I'm sure there is some misconception about how discord API handles coroutines. Here's a basic example:

```
active_sessions = {}

@bot.command()
async def first_command(ctx):

    # Saving the coroutine in the dictionary with the user ID as key:
    active_sessions[ctx.author.id] = ctx.command.callback

    # do stuff

@bot.command()
async def second_command(ctx):

    # Accessing the coroutine object and trying to stop it.
    try:
        coro = active_sessions[ctx.author.id]
        coro.close()
    
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

which throws an `AttributeError` stating that function object has no attribute close.
But, as per discord.py docs, `command.callback` refers to a coroutine object that should have the close method. Also tried `coro.cancel()` with the same result.

I'm conceptually doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what exactly, and also I have no clue how to implement my idea correctly, so any help is very appreciated.

## EDIT

So, since my goal might still be unclear, here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm doing a discord bot that is sort of a game. Users can run several commands, many of which would wait for a certain amount of time for a reaction or message from the command author.

But this user might run another command without 'completing' the first one, and if they come back to the first, their reactions would still be accepted.

I'm trying to avoid this behaviour and keep the user focused on a 'single session'; whatever command they run, the execution of the previous one needs to be automatically stopped.

So how I'm implementing this, which comes from a wrong misconception of coroutines, is having a dictionary that associates each user with the loop of the command thy're currently running. If another loop starts with the other one still running, the 'old loop' would be stopped and the respective entry in the dictionary would be updated with the new loop:

```
active_sessions = {}

@bot.command()
async def first_command(ctx):

    # In this first command I want to assign the current loop to a variable and
    # add it to the active_sessions dictionary along with the ID of the command author.
    
    # Then there's a loop that waits for user's reaction. 
    # Ignore the details such as the check function.       
    while True:
        try:
           reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",timeout=60,check=check)
           
           # some if conditions here make the bot behave differently according 
           # to the specific reaction added
        
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
           return

@bot.command()
async def second_command(ctx):

    # As soon as this second command is invoked, I need to access the 'loop object' 
    # previously stored in the dictionary (if any) and stop it from here.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with. `coro.cancel`? The `ctx.command.callback` returns a coroutine, not a running loop that can be cancelled

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I'm sure I'm referring to the wrong object there. How can I manage a specific loop from another one, if that's even possible?

Comment: It certainly is. But you should make it clear, what are you trying to stop or control? Your current method will definitely not work. More insight on what you are trying to do will help to get answers easily.

Comment: Edited with more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to actually stop the `wait_for` from working.

1. Switching to a bot event.

```py
import json
@bot.event()
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
   # use a config variable
   with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
   if data['wait_for_reaction']:
       # do stuff here
   else:
       return

@commands.command()
async def activate(ctx):
    #activates the listenere
    with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
    data['wait_for_reaction'] = True
    with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
       json.write(data, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send('activated listener')

@commands.command()
async def deactivate(ctx):
with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
    data['wait_for_reaction'] = False
    with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
       json.write(data, f, indent=4)
    await ctx.send('activated listener')
```

You can also use a global variable or a `.env` file to load the config variable

2. Using a task

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=0)
async def task(ctx):
   try: 
       reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",timeout=60, check=check)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       return

@commands.command():
async def activate(ctx):
   try: 
      task.start(ctx)
   except RuntimeError:
      await ctx.send("task is already running")
   finally:
      await ctx.send('started task')

@commands.command()
async def deactivate(ctx):
   task.stop()
   await ctx.send('stopped task')
```

The problem is tasks is that you can only run one task at once, so you cannot use the command in multiple contexts. There is a workaround but I wouldn't recommend using it. Use tasks only if your bot is a personal one that only you run.

### References:

- [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#)

Note:
If you are going to use a `.env` file to store your variable. Look into [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I find the first approach very interesting. The problem is I might need the on_reaction listener enabled for one command while disabled for another one so I cannot manage it with boolean flags.